# eliminate malformed records from a large .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a large `.csv` file and I want to processes it with, perhaps a python script, and find all the values that are "malformed", e.g. those that have more or less values than the number of headers, and eliminate them.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `(line for line in file if line.count(',') != n)`

Comment: Use the `csv.reader` class documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html). Each row is represented as a list. The length of this list therefore represents the number of columns in that particular row.

Comment: aha- so count the number of values in a line- and if it's not right- delete it? or don't write it to output?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I would not recommend using this method, because commas may be contained *within* records which are bounded by double-quotes (or whatever qualifier is used in that particular CSV file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic example:

```
num_headers = 5
with open("input.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("output.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    for i, line in enumerate(file_in):
        if len(line.split(",")) == num_headers:
            file_out.write(line)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

Or using the csv module (which is more flexible for different types of CSV formatting):

```
import csv
num_headers = 5
with open("input.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("output.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(file_in)
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in):
        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

Comment: is this python 2? i got the error "IOError: file not open for writing"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. file_out needs to be opened in write mode. I updated my code to fix that and include a second example.

Comment: Yes, this is Python 2. It should run in Python 3 if you change the print statement to a print function: _print("line %d is malformed" % i)_